# How to correctly toggle element in React (if it is in array)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have CommentSection component right here

```
    export class CommentSection extends Component {

    <...> some stuff that is not related to question    

    render() {
        if (!this.state.data || !this.state.data.length)
            return null;     
        var comments = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
            var item = this.state.data[i]; // single comment
            var commentReplies = this.pushReplies(item.id, i);                      
            if (item.replyToId == null) {
                comments.push( // pushing comment if it has replies
                    <React.Fragment key={'b' + i}>
                        <div className="comment">
                            <p className="comments_username">{item.userName}</p>
                            <p className="comments_body">{item.body}</p>
                            <p className="comments_date"> {item.publicationDate}</p>
                            <p className="reply">Reply</p>
                        </div>                        
                        <SmallCommentForm postId={this.state.id} replyToId={item.id} />

                        {commentReplies}

                    </React.Fragment>
                );
            } 

        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {comments}
            </React.Fragment >
        );
    }
}
```

I need to toggle `<SmallCommentForm>` component, but I can't correctly see how I can do it. Should I somehow add/remove `display:none` attributes from document.getElementById(replyToId) or what?

Almost every solution that I've seen contains *if statement* which decides should it render code or not. But I can't apply this kind of solution in that case: all comments have only one state, because I am using `for () {}`

Is there any solutions or am I doing it all wrong? Sorry for my English, it's not my primary language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can have another attribute for toggling the `<SmallCommentForm />`
So you have your data in an array in `this.state` and you have another attribute for the toggle and do `{ this.state.isOn && <SmallCommentForm />}`